# SQL DATEDIFF between multiple entries with same id

Tags: sql, subquery, datediff

I want to calculate the days between 2 dates on multiple entries but I have this error:

*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

I'm trying to use a LAG() but I can't find a solution.

[Data to read]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7X35.png)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
DAY,
(SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(dat.year, dat.month, dat.day)
FROM FactReport
JOIN DimDate AS dat ON dat.id = factReport.updatedDateId
WHERE bugId IN (
SELECT bugid FROM FactReport
GROUP BY bugid HAVING count(*) > 1)),

LAG(
(SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(dat.year, dat.month, dat.day)
FROM FactReport
JOIN DimDate AS dat ON dat.id = factReport.updatedDateId
WHERE bugId IN (
SELECT bugid FROM FactReport
GROUP BY bugid HAVING count(*) > 1)
)) 
OVER (ORDER BY FactReport.bugid))

as TimeToUpdate
FROM FactReport
```

Comment: The error message says it all, your query has one (or more) subqeury returning more than 1 row. Perhaps you want to LEFT JOIN them instead? Or make sure none of them return more than 1 row. (In a way that makes sense...)

Comment: LEFT JOIN doesn't work. Same error.